# Reducing code redundancy while creating XML with XOM

Tags: java, xml, xml-serialization, xom

I am using XOM as my XML parsing library. And i am using this for creating XML also. Below is the scenario described with example.

**Scenario:**

Code:

```
Element root =  new Element("atom:entry", "http://www.w3c.org/Atom");
Element city = new Element("info:city", "http://www.myinfo.com/Info");
city.appendChild("My City");
root.appendChild(city);     
Document d = new Document(root);
System.out.println(d.toXML());
```

Generated XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<atom:entry xmlns:atom="http://www.w3c.org/Atom">
   <info:city xmlns:info="http://www.myinfo.com/Info">
       My City
   </info:city>
</atom:entry>
```

Notice in the XML that here `info` namespace is added with the node itself. But I need this to be added in root element. like below

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<atom:entry xmlns:atom="http://www.w3c.org/Atom" xmlns:info="http://www.myinfo.com/Info">
   <info:city>
       My City
   </info:city>
</atom:entry>
```

And to do that, i just need following piece of code

```
Element root =  new Element("atom:entry", "http://www.w3c.org/Atom");
=> root.addNamespaceDeclaration("info", "http://www.myinfo.com/Info");
Element city = new Element("info:city", "http://www.myinfo.com/Info");
... ... ...
```

Problem is here i had to add `http://www.myinfo.com/Info` twice. And in my case there are hundreds of namespaces. So there will so too much redendancy. Is there any way to get rid of this redundancy?

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no way to get rid of this redundancy and that's a deliberate decision. In XOM the namespace is a fundamental part of the element itself, not a function of its position in the document.

Of course you could always declare a named constant for the namespace URI.